# Update an object creates new object in stripes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus, stripes

Whenever want to update an object,view by Id is fetching the detch clean object but when saving after the changes,stripes creates an object by setting fields value's one by one.so state of the object getting transient.

So,I want to ask is there any way to use the same object which has been fetched from database and after modification saving the same with its detached dirty state?

as because for new object it will always have transient state.

I am using stripes,Datanueclus JDO,google app engine,java

Comment: You mean the same as this question asks ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667595/is-there-any-way-to-update-using-a-transient-object-in-jdo

Comment: Yes, this is for the same problem,I actually wanted to know the exact cause of this problem.Does stripes framework update operation works like this i.e creates new object every time and setting value one by one,is there any way to stop object being created when updating and using same object with it's state.